# How can I aggregate strings from many cells into one cell?

Tags: pandas, string-concatenation, pairing

Say I have two classes with a handful of students each, and I want to think of the possible pairings in each class. In my original data, I have one line per student.

What's the easiest way in Pandas to turn this dataset

```
   Class Students
0      1  A
1      1  B
2      1  C
3      1  D
4      1  E
5      2  F
6      2  G
7      2  H
```

Into this new stuff?

```
   Class Students
0       1  A,B
1       1  A,C
2       1  A,D
3       1  A,E
4       1  B,C
5       1  B,D
6       1  B,E
7       1  C,D
6       1  B,E
8       1  C,D
9       1  C,E
10      1  D,E
11      2  F,G
12      2  F,H
12      2  G,H
```

Comment: show us what you tried.

Comment: Kinda dumb stuff, multistepped. Still working on the second step. This was the first one:

`for i in school['class'].unique():
  class.append(i)
  pairs.append(list(combinations(school[school['class']==i]['student'], 2)))`

Comment: I believe you should include any code that you have tried in the body of the question. This avoids downvotes related to question quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

cla = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
s = ["A", "B", "C", "D" , "E", "F", "G", "H"]
df = pd.DataFrame(cla, columns=["Class"])
df['Student'] = s


def create_combos(list_students):
    combos = itertools.combinations(list_students, 2)
    str_students = []
    for i in combos:
        str_students.append(str(i[0])+","+str(i[1]))
    return str_students

def iterate_df(class_id):
    df_temp = df.loc[df['Class'] == class_id]
    list_student = list(df_temp['Student'])
    list_combos = create_combos(list_student)
    list_id = [class_id for i in list_combos]
    return list_id, list_combos

list_classes = set(list(df['Class']))
new_id = []
new_combos = []
for idx in list_classes:
    tmp_id, tmp_combo = iterate_df(idx)
    new_id += tmp_id
    new_combos += tmp_combo

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_id, columns=["Class"])
new_df["Student"] = new_combos

print(new_df)
```

Comment: please accept the answer if it helpful for your question

Comment: Thank you a real lot!

Comment: don't forget accepting the answer